# Getting started with aor-permissions (admin-on-rest permissions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have read almost all the documentation aor-permissions available on internet. I am not starting a new project. I already have a project setup. This is my login method right now:

```
function getRoutes(store) {

    function hasAuth(nextState, replace, callback){
        const state = store.getState();
        const valid = !!state.tokenReducer.token;

        debug('AUTH: ', valid)

        if (valid){
            console.log("I am inside client routes line 44")
            debug('AUTH: Bailing. Already Valid.')
            return callback()
        }
        replace('/login')
        debug('AUTH: To Login')
        callback();
    }

    return (
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
            {/*<Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>*/}
            <Route path="/app" onEnter={hasAuth}>
```

Login component

```
class LoginPage extends Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    toApp() {
        console.log("login ajax called")
        //event.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        let token;
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
                "username": document.getElementById("username").value
            },
            success: (response, textStatus, jQxhr) => {

                this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token, "apurv");


            }
        }


        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

            token = response.auth_token
            window.localStorage.token_auth = token;
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });
```

Now I am trying to start using aor-permissions. The first thing it asks to do is something like this

```
// in authClient.js
import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_CHECK, AUTH_ERROR } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS } from 'aor-permissions';
import { decode } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default (type, params) => {
    // to login, fetch token and role from auth server, and store them in local storage
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        const { username, password } = params;
        const request = new Request('https://example.com/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        })
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                const decoded = decode(token);
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                localStorage.setItem('role', decoded.role);
            });
    }
    // ... usual authClient code

    // now simply read permissions from local storage
    if (type === AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS) {
        return Promise.resolve(localStorage.getItem('role'));
    }
};
```

I don't have any authClient.js. How can I stitch my current structure with aor and start using it. The first step is not at all clear to me.

Comment: Why aren't you using an `authClient` ? See https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [authclient](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#authclient) is completely optional, if you want to write your own logic for a lot of things which are already in built in admin-on-rest such as authentication and login hooks.

But, if you want to use aor-permissions, I think you will have to go through authclient.

Also, you are making a /login route separately, so, I am assuming you don't know that you have a /login route already built in [Admin](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html) component, if you are using Admin component. You just have to change [loginPage](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#loginpage) prop of Admin component to customize the login view.

> By default, an admin-on-rest app doesn’t require authentication. But
>   if the REST API ever returns a 401 (Unauthorized) or a 403 (Forbidden)
>   response, then the user is redirected to the /login route. You have
>   nothing to do - it’s already built in.

The source of above quote is @ [Authentication](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html).

And in case you are not using Admin component at all, then, you will have to write your own login and authentication system. For more information visit - making [custom app](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html) using admin-on-rest.

And if you already have the app written and want to integrate aor-permissions, you may like to go through the documentation of [aor-permissions](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-permissions#api). In api section you may find interesting components like SwitchPermissions, WithPermission, etc., which might help you, where authClient function is passed to these components rather than in Admin component.

Hope it helps.

Comment: as you can see in my Login Component, I have logic to check the success of login rest api. If it is success then I take the user to /app. If it is failed then it stays on /login. Now what if I want start from this point itself. The login check is setup already. Is there anything which is missing? Also I was planning to use aor-permissioon for restricting one type of user role to not access a particular page. Or not show show a button to one type of user role.

Comment: You can have the redirection behavior using the authClient as specified in the documentation and custom sagas

Comment: As I mentioned in the last paragraph, before "Hope it helps", you may want to use SwitchPermissions component, in which, you have to pass authClient prop which shall be used to check the permissions and then, you can use aor-permissions without using authClient prop in the Admin component. Look here - https://github.com/marmelab/aor-permissions#switchpermissions